# linq: groupby with multiple nullable types

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following table:

```
| AppointID | UserID | AppointSet | AppointAttended | AppointCancelled | AppointRescheduled |
|     1     |   1    |  2/15/2011 |                 |   3/11/2011      |                    |
|     2     |   1    |  2/17/2011 |                 |                  |    3/11/2011       |
|     3     |   1    |  3/11/2011 |   3/11/2011     |                  |                    |
|     4     |   1    |  3/10/2011 |                 |   3/11/2011      |
```

|

What I'm trying to do is create the following output that counts the activity by day.

```
|    Date     |   Set   |   Attended   |   Rescheduled   |   Cancelled   |
|  3/10/2011  |    1    |              |                 |               |
|  3/11/2011  |    1    |      1       |       1         |      2        |
```

Note that I've defined the fields AppointAttended, AppointCancelled and AppointRescheduled as nullable because there might not be a date for these.

This is what I have so far and I'm struggling with the groupby because I need to group by multiple columns, and it's a nullable type, and I can't get the .Key to work! In other words, I feel really stuck with this:

```
var OutputMonthlyActivity = from appnt in MyDC.LeadsAppointments
where appnt.UserID == TheUserID
where (appnt.AppointSet.Month == TheDate.Month && appnt.AppointSet.Year == TheDate.Year) ||
(appnt.AppointAttended.Value.Month == TheDate.Month && appnt.AppointAttended.Value.Year == TheDate.Year) ||
(appnt.AppointRescheduled.Value.Month == TheDate.Month && appnt.AppointRescheduled.Value.Year == TheDate.Year) ||
(appnt.AppointCancelled.Value.Month == TheDate.Month && appnt.AppointCancelled.Value.Year == TheDate.Year)
group appnt by new { appnt.AppointSet, appnt.AppointRescheduled, appnt.AppointAttended, appnt.AppointCancelled } into daygroups
where daygroups.Count() > 1
select new ViewMonthlyActivityModel()
{

ViewDate = daygroups.Key,

CountTotalSetOnDay = (from c in daygroups
where c.AppointSet.Date == daygroups.Key
select c.AppointID).Count(),
```

TheDate is a datetime that's passed in as a parameter and that represents the 1st day of the month that's queried: 3/1/2011 for the month of the March for example.

I get "An anonymous type cannot have multiple properties with the same name" in the groupby statement and the .Key doesn't work so the grouping by day is not working.

If you have any suggestions, that'd be really appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to explicitly set the right names of the properties of you anonymous type on which you group:

```
group appnt by new {
                     Set = appnt.AppointSet,
                     Rescheduled = appnt.AppointRescheduled,
                     Attended = appnt.AppointAttended,
                     Cancelled = appnt.AppointCancelled } into daygroups
```

Comment: ok, that clears the syntax errors. Now I have a problem with ViewDate = daygroups.Key. It works if I add something like = daygroups.Key.Set for instance: it'll group by that key. However, how do I ensure that I get a date no matter what (ie, could be that Set = null and then what goes into ViewDate?)

Comment: I got the line with the ViewDate: (from d in daygroups select d.AppointDatetime.Date).First(), The problem is that when I send 3/1/2011 as TheDate, I get all the appointments from Februray 26th to April 2nd. Any idea why?

Comment: The syntax works but the output is weird: I get dates that aren't within the month and the results are either 1s or 0s.

Comment: Maybe there are logic errors because of invalid group by statement. I don't think that it's correct. What if you group by each of column and then use `union` statement to unite all results in one table?

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. I've rephrased the question here because I've evolved the query a bit. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5254099/linq-group-by-good-syntax-but-weird-output