# linq group by: good syntax but weird output

Tags: c#, linq

The syntax of my query is good but not the output and it's really strange.

I have the following table:

```
| AppointID | UserID | AppointSet | AppointAttended | AppointCancelled | AppointRescheduled | AppointmentDatetime
|     1     |   1    |  2/15/2011 |                 |   3/11/2011      |                    |  3/15/2011
|     2     |   1    |  2/17/2011 |                 |                  |    3/11/2011       |  3/10/2011
|     3     |   1    |  3/11/2011 |   3/11/2011     |                  |                    |  3/25/2011
|     4     |   1    |  3/10/2011 |                 |   3/11/2011      |                    |  3/11/2011
```

What I'm trying to do is create the following output that counts the activity by day.

```
|    Date     |   Set   |   Attended   |   Rescheduled   |   Cancelled   |
|  3/10/2011  |    1    |              |                 |               |
|  3/11/2011  |    1    |      1       |       1         |      2        |
```

Note that I've defined the fields AppointAttended, AppointCancelled and AppointRescheduled as nullable because there might not be a date for these.

The query is as follows:

```
var OutputMonthlyActivity = from appnt in MyDC.LeadsAppointments
where appnt.UserID == TheUserID
where (appnt.AppointSet.Year == TheDate.Year && appnt.AppointSet.Month == TheDate.Month) ||
(appnt.AppointAttended.Value.Year == TheDate.Year && appnt.AppointAttended.Value.Month == TheDate.Month) ||
(appnt.AppointRescheduled.Value.Year == TheDate.Year && appnt.AppointRescheduled.Value.Month == TheDate.Month) ||
(appnt.AppointCancelled.Value.Year == TheDate.Year && appnt.AppointCancelled.Value.Month == TheDate.Month)
group appnt by new { SetOn = appnt.AppointSet.Date, ReschedOn = appnt.AppointRescheduled.Value.Date, Attended = appnt.AppointAttended.Value.Date, Cancelled = appnt.AppointCancelled.Value.Date } into daygroups
select new ViewMonthlyActivityModel()
{

ViewDate = (from d in daygroups select d.AppointDatetime.Date).First(),

CountTotalSetOnDay = (from c in daygroups
where c.AppointSet.Date == daygroups.Key.SetOn
select c.AppointID).Count(),

CountAttendedOnDay = (from c in daygroups
where c.AppointAttended.HasValue == true
select c.AppointID).Count(),

CountRescheduledOnDay = (from c in daygroups
where c.AppointRescheduled.HasValue == true
select c.AppointID).Count(),

CountCancelledOnDay = (from c in daygroups
where c.AppointCancelled.HasValue == true
select c.AppointID).Count()

};
```

TheDate is a parameter I pass that represents a date in the month I'm querying (ie March 1st). The problem is that in addition to all the dates of March, I'm getting results from the last 2 days of February and the first 2 days of April. Also, each day comes out with 3 rows.

If you have any suggestions, that'd be really appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Does each row only use one of the three outcomes (attended,cancelled,rescheduled)?

Comment: I changed a few things: each day comes out with three rows. Row1 = count of set in both the set and cancelled column; row2 = count of attended in both the set and the attended column; row 3 = count of rescheduled in both the set and the rescheduled columns. So yes, each row is only one of the outcomes.

Comment: Probably not what you need right now, but if possible, you might consider a schema change where these 3 cols are reduced to only two, resolveDate and resolveReason. It's going to make querying considerably less arduous, and will consume less space. Imagine being able to groupby resolveReason... tempted?

Comment: That's a possibility that makes sense. For the moment I'm looking to fix this query and it looks like I'm not that far. It has to day with the grouping. Your suggestion sounds tempting; I'm thinking about how the updates might work in both models.

Comment: I'll still be stuck on the same groupby problem no? I'll have the count of all sets, scheduled, cancelled and attended appointments but the grouping problem will be the same it seems.

Comment: I tried running your code. Where does d.AppointDatetime.Date come from?

Comment: It's a field in the table that's the date at which the appointment is due; editing the question to include this field.

Comment: For instance, on row 1: the appointment was set in mid-february for mid-march but was cancelled on 3/11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be that your group has some anonymous object as its key.

You are grouping each appointment by an object:

```
new { SetOn = appnt.AppointSet.Date, ReschedOn = appnt.AppointRescheduled.Value.Date, Attended = appnt.AppointAttended.Value.Date, Cancelled = appnt.AppointCancelled.Value.Date } into daygroups
```

Instead, you should be grouping by the actual key, such as the AppointmentDatetime.

Actually, for what you are trying to do, I don't believe you need to group by at all.

Assuming the following sample data:

[image: sample data]

```
// First, get all appointments for the following user
var TheUserID = 1;
var appointments = from appointment in Appointments where appointment.UserID == TheUserID select appointment;

// Then, find all unique dates
var uniqueDates = appointments.Select(a => a.AppointSet)
    .Union(appointments.Where(a => a.AppointAttended.HasValue).Select(a => a.AppointAttended.Value))
    .Union(appointments.Where(a => a.AppointCancelled.HasValue).Select(a => a.AppointCancelled.Value))
    .Union(appointments.Where(a => a.AppointRescheduled.HasValue).Select(a => a.AppointRescheduled.Value))
    .Union(appointments.Select(a => a.AppointmentDatetime))
      // Filter by the month/year
    .Where(x => x.Month == TheDate.Month && x.Year == TheDate.Year)
      // Finally, select a new object for each unique date holding the counts
    .Select(x => new {
        Date = x,
        Cancelled = appointments.Where(a => a.AppointCancelled.HasValue && a.AppointCancelled.Value == x).Count(),
        Rescheduled = appointments.Where(a => a.AppointRescheduled.HasValue && a.AppointRescheduled.Value == x).Count(),
        Set = appointments.Where(a => a.AppointSet == x).Count(),
        Attended = appointments.Where(a => a.AppointAttended.HasValue && a.AppointAttended.Value == x).Count()
    });
```

This should result in the following output:

[image: report output]

Is this what you're trying to do?

Comment: That's exactly what I'm trying to do! All I need is to add the month selector: I pass in the value TheDate and the return query only selects the appointments where the activity (set, cancelled, rescheduled, attended) took place during that month. Now, I'm in the process of changing the model; I'm about half-way (need to update the dummy data). The new table will have AppointSet, ResolveDate, ResolveStatus (byte ranging from 1-4). I'll group by status. In terms of performance, what do you think would be better? Keep the current model or go with the updated one? Think of update queries too.

Comment: Well, having one date to query for instead of 4 should mean faster performance, generally. I don't see how it'd make a difference for update queries, though, since you'd probably be updating by ID and not by any other column, right?

Comment: Ok, I got back at it and changed the model. The query is much simpler but I'm stuck on it too. I'm having some troubles with the group by. If you have a moment, I posted the question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265338/linq-groupby-with-new-type  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you can't change the schema, I'd start by reshaping the data a little:

```
var appoinments = MyDC
.LeadsAppointments
.Select(la => new 
    {
        somefields = somedata, //fill in the blanks
        resolveDate =
            la.AppointAttended  ??
            la.AppointCancelled ??
            la.AppointRescheduled,
        resolveReason = 
            la.AppointAttended != null ? 0 : la.AppointCancelled != null ? 1 : 2
    })
```

Now we make a 2 flat tables of dates vs reasons (0,1,2 are attended,cancelled,rescheduled and 4 is set)

```
var setDates = appointments
    .Select(a => new {Date = a.Date, Reason = 4});

var otherDates = appointments
    .Select(a => new {Date = a.resolveDate,Reason = a.ResolveReason});
```

UnionAll the two tables above:

```
var allDates = setDates.Concat(otherDates);
```

And group:

```
var groups = allDates.GroupBy(a => new{a.Date, a.Reason});
```

So to query a specific day:

```
groups
    .Where(g => g.Key.Date == someDate)
    .Select(g=> new{g.Key.Reason, Count = g.Key.Count()})
```

which should (if my completely untested code is anywhere near working) show 4 rows with counts for each reason.

Not the shape you want, but it wouldn't be difficult to pivot if that's what you need.

Comment: Changing the model looks like the better option. However, the query will be quite similar. How will the grouping be different?

Comment: I'm going to copy the table and try changing the model. For now I'm at design time so I can try this and it looks like it might be easier to do now than trying so voodoo on a live app.

Comment: That looks like a solution; I'm changing the model around but if I can't get it to work with the 2 column option (resolveDate, resolveStatus) then I'll try this. Thanks for looking into it.

Comment: Yes, if you can get it in the schema, then you can index the resolveStatus and date columns for a big speedup.

Comment: Ok, I followed your recommendation and changed the model. I'm still stuck on the groupby statement. I posted the question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265338/linq-groupby-with-new-type  If you have a moment to take a look at it that'd be really nice. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You could produce separate counts for each column and then join them all together, like this (I've only done it for AppointSet and AppointAttend but the rest would be simple):

```
        var userAppoints = from appnt in MyDC.LeadsAppointments
                           where appnt.UserID == TheUserID
                           select appnt;

        var appntSets = from appnt in userAppoints
                        where appnt.AppointSet.Year == TheDate.Year && appnt.AppointSet.Month == TheDate.Month
                        group appnt by appnt.AppointSet
                        into groups
                        select new ViewMonthlyActivityModel()
                            {
                                ViewDate = groups.Key,
                                CountTotalSetOnDay = groups.Count()
                            };

        var appntAttends = from appnt in userAppoints
                           where appnt.AppointAttended != null && appnt.AppointAttended.Value.Year == TheDate.Year && appnt.AppointAttended.Value.Month == TheDate.Month
                           group appnt by appnt.AppointAttended.Value
                           into groups
                           select new ViewMonthlyActivityModel()
                               {
                                   ViewDate = groups.Key,
                                   CountAttendedOnDay = groups.Count()
                               };

        var allModels = appntSets.Concat(appntAttends).GroupBy(a => a.ViewDate, (date, models) => new ViewMonthlyActivityModel 
        { 
            ViewDate = date, 
            CountTotalSetOnDay = models.Aggregate(0, (seed, model) => seed + model.CountTotalSetOnDay), 
            CountAttendedOnDay = models.Aggregate(0, (seed, model) => seed + model.CountAttendedOnDay) 
        });
```