# LINQ groupby statement with key

Tags: c#, .net, linq, group-by

The syntax of my query is good but not the output and it's really strange.

I have the following table:

```
| AppointID | UserID | AppointSet | AppointResolved |  AppointStatus | AppointmentDatetime
|     1     |   1    |  3/1/2011  |   3/1/2011      |      1         |     3/15/2011
|     2     |   1    |  3/2/2011  |   3/5/2011      |      4         |     3/16/2011
|     3     |   1    |  3/2/2011  |   3/11/2011     |      2         |     3/11/2011
|     4     |   1    |  3/3/2011  |   3/7/2011      |      3         |     3/25/2011
```

ApponintStatus is a byte where 1 is for set, 2 is for attended, 3 is for rescheduled and 4 is for cancelled. AppointDatetime is the date for which is appointment is set.

What I'm trying to do is create the following output that counts the activity by day.

```
|    Date     |   Set   |   Attended   |   Rescheduled   |   Cancelled   |
|  3/1/2011   |    1    |              |                 |               |
|  3/2/2011   |    2    |              |                 |               |
|  3/3/2011   |    1    |              |                 |               |
|  3/5/2011   |         |              |                 |      1        |
|  3/7/2011   |         |      1       |                 |               |
|  3/11/2011  |         |              |        1        |               |
```

This is what I have so far. TheDate is a date within the month I'm querying for (ie, pass March 4th and should return the March table)

```
var r = from appnt in MyDC.LeadsAppointments
        where appnt.UserID == TheUserID
        where (appnt.AppointResolved.Year == TheDate.Year && appnt.AppointResolved.Month == TheDate.Month) ||
        (appnt.AppointSet.Year == TheDate.Year && appnt.AppointSet.Month == TheDate.Month)
        group appnt by appnt.AppointResolved.Date into daygroups
        select new ViewMonthlyActivityModel()
        {
            ViewDate = (from d in daygroups
                        select daygroups.Key.Date).First(), // Problem here: need to get dates for instances where an appointment is set but none are resolved

            CountTotalSetOnDay = (from c in daygroups
                                  where c.AppointSet.Date == daygroups.Key // Problem here
                                  select c.AppointID).Count(),

            CountAttendedOnDay = (from c in daygroups
                                  where c.AppointResolved.Date == daygroups.Key.Date
                                  where c.AppointStatus == 2
                                  select c.AppointID).Count(),
```

One of the problem is that CountTotalSetOnDay is returning only the count of those that are set and resolved the same day; the other problem is that ViewDate needs to return all the dates: there are dates when there are no appointments set but appointments attended, rescheduled or cancelled, and vice versa, there are dates when appointments are set but none are resolved.

For now I'm running this with 2 queries and I join the results: one query returns the appointments set and the other returns the appointments resolved. However, I'm still stuck on the solution with one query in one read.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the solution with 2 read queries works just fine and will stand for now.

Answer (score 2):

You need to group using both the Set date and the Resolved date.  This could easily be achieved by adding another `from` clause doing a cross join with the set of dates and grouping by those dates.

The query below is based on a LINQ to Objects query.  LINQ to SQL does not support this kind of query so you'll have to decide if you want to use this which runs on the client machine or on the server.

```
const byte statusAttended = 2;
const byte statusRescheduled = 3;
const byte statusCancelled = 4;
var query = from a in MyDC.LeadsAppointments.AsEnumerable()
            from date in new[] { a.AppointSet.Date, a.AppointResolved.Date }
            where a.UserID == TheUserID
               && date.Year == TheDate.Year
               && date.Month == TheDate.Month
            group a by date into g
            orderby g.Key
            let set = g.Distinct().ToList()
            select new ViewMonthlyActivityModel
            {
                ViewDate = g.Key,
                CountTotalSetOnDay =
                    set.Count(a => a.AppointSet.Date == g.Key),
                CountTotalAttendedOnDay =
                    set.Count(a => a.AppointResolved.Date == g.Key
                                && a.AppointStatus == statusAttended),
                CountTotalRescheduledOnDay =
                    set.Count(a => a.AppointResolved.Date == g.Key
                                && a.AppointStatus == statusRescheduled),
                CountTotalCancelledOnDay =
                    set.Count(a => a.AppointResolved.Date == g.Key
                                && a.AppointStatus == statusCancelled),
            };
```

---

Otherwise for a completely LINQ to SQL solution (not the cleanest) that should work, you can try this.  There might be a nicer way to do this but I don't know of it.

```
const byte statusAttended = 2;
const byte statusRescheduled = 3;
const byte statusCancelled = 4;
var query = from a in MyDC.LeadsAppointments
            let setDate = from aa in MyDC.LeadsAppointments
                          where aa.AppointID == a.AppointID
                          select aa.AppointSet.Date
            let resolvedDate = from aa in MyDC.LeadsAppointments
                               where aa.AppointID == a.AppointID
                               select aa.AppointResolved.Date
            from date in setDate.Concat(resolvedDate)
            where a.UserID == TheUserID
               && date.Year == TheDate.Year
               && date.Month == TheDate.Month
            group a by date into g
            orderby g.Key
            let set = g.Distinct()
            select new ViewMonthlyActivityModel
            {
                ViewDate = g.Key,
                CountTotalSetOnDay =
                    set.Count(a => a.AppointSet.Date == g.Key),
                CountTotalAttendedOnDay =
                    set.Count(a => a.AppointResolved.Date == g.Key
                                && a.AppointStatus == statusAttended),
                CountTotalRescheduledOnDay =
                    set.Count(a => a.AppointResolved.Date == g.Key
                                && a.AppointStatus == statusRescheduled),
                CountTotalCancelledOnDay =
                    set.Count(a => a.AppointResolved.Date == g.Key
                                && a.AppointStatus == statusCancelled),
            };
```

Comment: I tested and retested it but it wasn't returning the correct results against by dummy data. I don't know why.

Comment: @frenchie: What is not right about either of these?  With your sample data, it matches the output (with attended and rescheduled dates swapped).  Are there cases that you left out?

Comment: I don't know why it's not working but when I test the output of the query against the sample data, the results are different. For instance, on the CountTotalSetDay, all my sample data is designed to show a count of 16 for each day and with this query I'm getting a count of 40 for each day. The query I put together works fine. It first gets all the Set, then all the other cases, and then combines both with a linq-to-object query. Yes, it does 2 reads but for the moment I'm going to leave it at that. Your code shows how the "let" statement works and that's helped me for something else. Thanks.

Comment: @frenchie: Would you mind posting that data and the expected results as well as updating your question to show your complete queries?  And if possible, make a generic example that I (and everyone else) can compile directly.  I can (and do) write dummy classes to fit your example but that's a lot of work I'd rather not be doing.  What I have here works for the example you gave us AFAIK and I can't be of any help if I don't have all the information you have.

Comment: That's rather involved; I can't just post a spreadsheet in a textbox. It's fine, the queries I have work for now.

Comment: @frenchie: In that case, a small enough example where your queries give you what you expect and these fail.  That would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You are grouping by AppointResolved.Date.

Therefore, for each entry in daygroups, daygroups.Key == AppointResolved.Date, and the c.AppointSet.Date == daygroups.Key where clause will only give you all the entries where the appointment was set the same day as it was resolved.

It seems to me that if you want to achieve your stated goal, you will have to list all dates mentioned in ANY of the fields of your table and count them.

For example, consider:

```
var appointmentsTaken = (from appnt in GoyaDC.LeadsAppointments
                         where ... // your filters
                         group appnt by appnt.AppointSet.Date into daysset
                         select { Date = daysset.Key Count = daysset.Count() }
```

This should give you a list of the dates where appointments where set, and for each, how many of them.

Comment: Yes, that's the problem I'm stuck on. And, there will also be cases where there's a date for which there's an appointment set but no appointment resolved.

Comment: It's just an example to show you how to get the 'Set' column from your table entries. If you do the same thing for every date and every required field in your output table, you should have all the information you need to fulfill your goal.

Comment: Ok, I'm still trying things out